# Copy ranges from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is a reasonably simple solution but I'm unable to locate an exact answer,

I have a VBA macro for importing CSV files into the same workbook which creates multiple sheets in the same workbook, I am trying to create a "Master" sheet before the worksheets that will copy data from A4:D8 and paste it on the master sheet below the previous copy,

It is very nearly working but it only pastes the value from the last worksheet (if i import 10 CSVs it will create a MASTER sheet but only the A4:D8 values from the last sheet will show up on master)

I think it is overwriting the data each time and finishing on the last sheet but I can't figure out why, as I presumed the .End(xlUp).Column+1 is finding the last row of data and adding below but doesn't appear to be the case

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

```
Sub MasterSheet3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer, col As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1)).Name = "Master"
    Sheets("Master").Activate
'Make a master sheet and select it

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
            ws.Range("A4:D8").Copy

            col = Worksheets("Master").Range("A:D").End(xlUp).Column + 1
            Worksheets("Master").Cells(1, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If

    Next ws
    Columns(1).Delete
    Range("A1").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `.End(xlUp).Column+1` moves one *column* to the right, not one *row* down...

Comment: Sorry I pasted a previous version  , row +1 was same issue,  but if it was functioning correctly surely I should have columns full of data instead of just one dataset in a1:d4

Comment: To find the last column you need to count the columns not the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub MasterSheet3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsMaster As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim j As Integer, col As Integer, rngPaste As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or Activeworkbook
    
    Set wsMaster = Sheets.Add(Before:=wb.Sheets(1))
    wsMaster.Name = "Master"
    wsMaster.Activate
    Set rngPaste = wsMaster.Range("A1") 'start copying to here...

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsMaster.Name Then
            With ws.Range("A4:D8")
                rngPaste.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
                Set rngPaste = rngPaste.Offset(.Rows.Count) 'move paste target down
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
    
    wsMaster.Columns(1).Delete
    wsMaster.Range("A1").Activate
    
End Sub
```